# FQL Query: Get all posts and comments made to my stream by friends only

Tags: facebook-fql

I am using the following FQL Query to all my friends from my friends list successfully:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
```

I'd like to use all of the uid2's returned to perform a second query (or just combine it into one big one !!!!) that grabs all comments, posts and messages on my news_feed by friends only.

Heres what I have so far that grabs friends and non-friends.

```
SELECT type, created_time, post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me())
```

I'm only concerned with grabbing content (messages and textual info) posted by friends only. If you have a query that could help that would be great. FYI I have already been to the FB **stream** table page.

Answer (score 0):

Append your 1st statement as another where clause to your 2nd:

```
SELECT type, created_time, post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key IN (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid = me())
AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It would seem that there are still comments from non-friends that show up in the data.